# copying a string into a structure array

Tags: c

So I have this code below, in my code i load a bunch of movies into an array of structures, Now i know the problem is happening in here 
     (strcpy(parts[x].rating,sp); and what it looks like the strcpy is not working properly, can anyone give me a hint or something useful i can use to solve the problem? I have tried doing it without the strcpy but it doesn't work either !

```
struct movies
{
char *name;
char *rating;
int time;
float rtwo,rone,rthree; 
};

void displayData(movies *);
 main ()
{
struct movies parts[6];
FILE *fp;
char line[100];

fp=fopen("movies.csv","r");
if (fp == NULL)
{
    printf("Could not locate file");
    exit(0);
}

char *sp;
int x = 0;
    while (fgets(line,100,fp)!=NULL) 
    { 

        sp=strtok(line,",");  
        strcpy(parts[x].name,sp);    


        sp=strtok(NULL,","); 
        strcpy(parts[x].rating,sp);  

        sp=strtok(NULL,","); 
        sscanf(sp,"%d", &parts[x].time);
        sp=strtok(NULL,","); 
        sscanf(sp,"%f", &parts[x].rone);
        sp=strtok(NULL,","); 
        sscanf(sp,"%f", &parts[x].rtwo);
        sp=strtok(NULL,","); 
        sscanf(sp,"%f", &parts[x].rthree); 
        ++x;
    } 
fclose(fp);
displayData(parts);
return 0;
}

void displayData(movies *parts)
{
for (int x=0; x < 6 ; ++x) 
{
    printf("\n Name: %s RATED: %s Time:%d crit: %.1f crit: %.1f crit: 
    %.0f",parts[x].name,parts[x].rating,parts[x]
    .time,parts[x].rone,parts[x].rtwo,pa
    rts[x].rthree); 

    }
}
```

Comment: and yes i did #include <string.h> and all other necessary libraries .

Comment: There is no array in your structure! A pointer is **not** an array!

Comment: Given `parts[x].name` is a pointer, what does it point to?

Comment: @Olaf A structure array is this ( movies parts[6]; ), look at my declaration!

Comment: @AliSoujod: That's an **array of structures**, not a "structure array"! Details are important in programming - gt used to them. As a sidenote: you cannot copy a string to an array of structures: wrong types! You can copy a C string (which is only a convention, not a distinct type) to an array of `char`, though. It is not relevant where the array is contained.

Comment: @AliSoujod: That's the problem with redundant information. Read your whole post! And it is not your's to allow or disallow me commenting.

Comment: @Olaf "redundant information" ? This is your first reply "There is no array in your structure! A pointer is not an array!", What does that have anything to do with solving my problem of allocating memory? My problem was solved by stephan and thanks to him, he looked at the problem and solved for it instead of criticizing what is a structure and what not. read this from the code again (movies parts[6]; ) << does this look like a pointer to you or an array of structures, like exactly what i had in my initial post? I doubt you have 20 years of experience, for a beginner like me to correct you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that you do not reserve target memory for the string you want to copy. Note that a `struct movies`-object provides a data member `name`, which allows to store a pointer to a sequence of character values, but not the character values themselfes. Hence, `strcpy(parts[x].name,sp)` accesses the (uninitialized) pointer `parts[0].name` (which is already UB by itself); the pointer points probably to "somewhere", and then you copy a string to "somewhere".

So you'd have to use `malloc` first, before calling `strcpy`; or you could use `strdup`, which does `malloc` and `strcpy` in one call:

```
    sp=strtok(line,",");  
    parts[x].name = malloc(strlen(sp)+1);
    strcpy(parts[x].name,sp);
```

or:

```
    sp=strtok(line,",");  
    parts[x].name = strdup(sp);
```

Further, you should check if `strtok` actually returned something valid, e.g. like:

```
    if ((sp=strtok(line,",")) == NULL)
       continue;
    parts[x].name = strdup(sp);
```

Comment: Thank you, it WORKED ! I looked at not one or two, but multiple examples from stack-overflow but couldn't find a solution!  now i understand that I have to allocate the memory before copying the string!

Answer (score 0):

Been a while since I played with C, but, don't you need to malloc parts[x].rating before using it? Same thing with parts[x].name and any other char pointer you have.